# static bool function in C++

Tags: c++, static, boolean

The function is defined as `static bool foo(const std::string& iVariable);` belongs to Class A.
When I use `if (A::foo（Var）)`， I found that the return value of A::foo(Var) will not change，I use it in many places, and `Var` is changed. So does it mean that the return value of A::foo(Var) will be fix, after the first time I use it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: so what's the problem/question?

Comment: Would you be surprised that the function `int f(int a) { return 3; }` always returns `3`, even if you vary the argument? Why is this surprising?

Comment: does he deserve the explorer badge?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: No, but the answerer should get the "Clairvoyeur" badge :-)

Comment: Try calling `foo("")`. (Yes, I'm trying to reconstruct `foo` from a series of input values. Expect a few more comments.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the documentation of A::foo and see if it says it ignores the argument after the first call. If it does say that, then you shouldn't expect the return value to change. If it doesn't say that, then you should expect the value to change in some way depending on the input and maybe other things that the documentation will hopefully tell you.

Of course the documentation could be wrong or misleading, in which case a look at the source code could clarify this.

If there is no documentation, I suggest you talk to the author of the code.

If you are the author, you may have some work to do.

Comment: I want the "clairvoyant" badge!